# How to make Laravel read .env file again?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm changing Laravel .env variable after a process, and checking that variable everytime, if it's true code doing one thing, if it's false another thing. But after changing the .env variable I have to restart with php artisan serve, I don't want to do this. Why Laravel does not read the new env variable, it changes on the .env file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to manipulate environment variables during runtime. If you're trying to manipulate an environment variable, you should probably instead utilize a config value. These configuration files are placed in the config/ directory of your project.

Then during runtime, you can use the following built-in config helper to get/set your config variable.

```
    $value = config('app.timezone');

    // To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper
    config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);

    $newValue = config('app.timezone');
```

You can read more about this process here (you can change the version to your version):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#accessing-configuration-values